# Why XeLaTeX and PDFLaTeX give different outputs for Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, xetex, pdftex

I have 3 questions:

1. Why does the following code (see below) give different results in XeLaTeX than PDFLaTeX?
2. Which one is incorrect? (My guess is that XeLaTeX's output is incorrect.)
3. How do I make the incorrect output become correct?

Here is the comparison (PDFLaTeX first, XeLaTeX second):

[image: PDFLaTeX]
[image: XeLaTeX]

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Madrid}}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=UseNone}
\title[Short Title]{The Longer Title}
\author{Author}
\institute[Institute]{Long Institute \\ \medskip \textit{email@domain.edu}}
\date{}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

The requested file lists are:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
 *File List*
  beamer.cls    2013/12/02 3.33 A class for typesetting presentations (rcs-revision 332bfd3ce558)
beamerbasercs.sty    2013/12/25 (rcs-revision 31cc758a62ae)
beamerbasemodes.sty    2013/09/03 (rcs-revision 768f2d98ca64)
beamerbasedecode.sty    2010/05/01 (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
beamerbaseoptions.sty    2013/03/10 (rcs-revision 47431932db0d)
  keyval.sty    2014/05/08 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
geometry.cfg
  size11.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/04/25 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)
  pgfrcs.sty    2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
 xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2011/06/24 v1.1 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
beamerbaserequires.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbasecompatibility.sty    2012/05/01  (rcs-revision 67c48b3b652d)
beamerbasefont.sty    2013/10/18  (rcs-revision 72f39e01808a)
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
sansmathaccent.sty    2013/03/28
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
beamerbasetranslator.sty    2010/06/11  (rcs-revision 85fd1cc7fc42)
translator.sty    2010/06/12 ver 1.10
translator-language-mappings.tex
beamerbasemisc.sty    2013/09/03  (rcs-revision a55719c41d85)
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseoverlay.sty    2013/12/25  (rcs-revision f6bd5e3805da)
beamerbasetitle.sty    2010/09/21  (rcs-revision f0446ed0b6ae)
beamerbasesection.sty    2013/06/07  (rcs-revision 60b9fe0f342f)
beamerbaseframe.sty    2013/10/02  (rcs-revision cdc8e9a3aaac)
beamerbaseverbatim.sty    2012/08/30  (rcs-revision dfdb135076b3)
beamerbaseframesize.sty    2011/09/12  (rcs-revision 70f9d8411e54)
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty    2013/10/18  (rcs-revision 5cf6c5555a45)
beamerbasecolor.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision d1a9b48be06d)
beamerbasenotes.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerbasetoc.sty    2013/05/23  (rcs-revision 0fdf5bc43be8)
beamerbasetemplates.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty    2013/09/04  (rcs-revision 4ac715c499d0)
beamerbaseboxes.sty    2012/05/13  (rcs-revision 56972908a390)
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty    2013/09/04  (rcs-revision 4ac715c499d0)
enumerate.sty    1999/03/05 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty    2013/10/05  (rcs-revision 62be157fe783)
beamerbasetheorems.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision 7e7cc5e53e9d)
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2004/08/06 v2.20
beamerbasethemes.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerthemedefault.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerfontthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamercolorthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerinnerthemedefault.sty    2013/10/15  (rcs-revision 65cb471f9634)
beamerouterthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerthemeMadrid.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamercolorthemewhale.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamercolorthemeorchid.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerinnerthemerounded.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty    2012/10/16  (rcs-revision 51a8c72084af)
supp-pdf.mkii
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-months-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict
```

and

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
 *File List*
  beamer.cls    2013/12/02 3.33 A class for typesetting presentations (rcs-revision 332bfd3ce558)
beamerbasercs.sty    2013/12/25 (rcs-revision 31cc758a62ae)
beamerbasemodes.sty    2013/09/03 (rcs-revision 768f2d98ca64)
beamerbasedecode.sty    2010/05/01 (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
beamerbaseoptions.sty    2013/03/10 (rcs-revision 47431932db0d)
  keyval.sty    2014/05/08 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
geometry.cfg
  size11.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/04/25 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
   xetex.def    2014/04/28 v4.01 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)
  pgfsys.sty    2013/11/30 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.47)
  pgfrcs.sty    2013/12/20 v3.0.0 (rcs-revision 1.28)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
 pgfcore.code.tex
 xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1
atbegshi.sty    2011/10/05 v1.16 At begin shipout hook (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
hyperref.sty    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2012/04/25 v1.12 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2007/09/27 v1.1 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2011/11/25 v1.13 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2012/04/08 v1.3 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2011/01/30 v1.1 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2011/01/30 v1.2 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2010/09/02 v1.4 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2011/06/24 v1.1 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2011/01/30 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2011/06/30 v1.8 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
refcount.sty    2011/10/16 v3.4 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2011/01/30 v1.7 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2011/03/04 v1.3 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  hxetex.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref driver for XeTeX
   puenc.def    2012/11/06 v6.83m Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
stringenc.sty    2011/12/02 v1.10 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO)
rerunfilecheck.sty    2011/04/15 v1.7 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
se-ascii-print.def    2011/12/02 v1.10 stringenc: Printable ASCII characters
beamerbaserequires.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbasecompatibility.sty    2012/05/01  (rcs-revision 67c48b3b652d)
beamerbasefont.sty    2013/10/18  (rcs-revision 72f39e01808a)
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
sansmathaccent.sty    2013/03/28
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
beamerbasetranslator.sty    2010/06/11  (rcs-revision 85fd1cc7fc42)
translator.sty    2010/06/12 ver 1.10
translator-language-mappings.tex
beamerbasemisc.sty    2013/09/03  (rcs-revision a55719c41d85)
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseoverlay.sty    2013/12/25  (rcs-revision f6bd5e3805da)
beamerbasetitle.sty    2010/09/21  (rcs-revision f0446ed0b6ae)
beamerbasesection.sty    2013/06/07  (rcs-revision 60b9fe0f342f)
beamerbaseframe.sty    2013/10/02  (rcs-revision cdc8e9a3aaac)
beamerbaseverbatim.sty    2012/08/30  (rcs-revision dfdb135076b3)
beamerbaseframesize.sty    2011/09/12  (rcs-revision 70f9d8411e54)
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty    2013/10/18  (rcs-revision 5cf6c5555a45)
beamerbasecolor.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision d1a9b48be06d)
beamerbasenotes.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerbasetoc.sty    2013/05/23  (rcs-revision 0fdf5bc43be8)
beamerbasetemplates.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty    2013/09/04  (rcs-revision 4ac715c499d0)
beamerbaseboxes.sty    2012/05/13  (rcs-revision 56972908a390)
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty    2013/09/04  (rcs-revision 4ac715c499d0)
enumerate.sty    1999/03/05 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty    2013/10/05  (rcs-revision 62be157fe783)
beamerbasetheorems.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision 7e7cc5e53e9d)
 amsmath.sty    2013/01/14 v2.14 AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
  amsopn.sty    1999/12/14 v2.01 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2004/08/06 v2.20
beamerbasethemes.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerthemedefault.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerfontthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamercolorthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerinnerthemedefault.sty    2013/10/15  (rcs-revision 65cb471f9634)
beamerouterthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerthemeMadrid.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamercolorthemewhale.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamercolorthemeorchid.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerinnerthemerounded.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty    2012/10/16  (rcs-revision 51a8c72084af)
 nameref.sty    2012/10/27 v2.43 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2010/12/03 v1.4 Cleanup title references (HO)
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-months-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict
```

Comment: I can spot no difference on my screen.

Comment: @egreg: You can't see a difference between the images I posted? The colors are different, the antialiasing is different... just test the RGB value for the blue box and compare the two documents.

Comment: Sorry, but I get the same colors. Are you using the same PDF reader?

Comment: Add `\listfiles` and post the two file lists please!

Comment: I can clearly see a difference on my calibrated monitor here: While pdflatex creates the blue as RGB 51,51,178, xelatex generates 67,71,151. I checked both files side by side in Adobe Reader.

Comment: @egreg: Are you talking about the PDF or about the screenshot? If you're talking about the PDF you rendered yourself, which of my screenshots is it similar to? I'm using Acrobat. (No, please don't tell me to change my PDF reader.)

Comment: I also cannot replicate this on my computer.

Comment: @percusse: it'd be more useful if you could give more info than just "can't-repro". Specifically, which one of the two images does your computer produce? And it'd be nice to know what OS you are on, and what PDF viewer?

Comment: @Mehrdad Take it easy. I have the same config with you because I saw your `\listfiles` output. Hence the comment.

Comment: @Mehrdad What if you pass an option to `xcolor` when loading `beamer`? Both outputs look the same on my machine if I use `\documentclass[xcolor=rgb]{beamer}`.

Comment: @erik: Nope, that option doesn't change anything for me.

Comment: @percusse: What OS and what version of Acrobat do you have though? That might change things.

Comment: Update: Google Chrome's PDF viewer shows both similarly to the PDFLaTeX version.

Comment: surprisingly on my current system it is the xelatex produced one which has the brighter colors with my old acroread. 9. If I open with Okular I see no obvious color differences. The  `xcolor=rgb` option has no effect on acroread visualization.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using pdfTeX in direct PDF output mode, you are looking at having different specials and so forth here. As such, it's hard to say one result is 'right' and the other is 'wrong', more that it's expected that the two will not be identical. Choose a compilation route and stick to it!